# What is the relationship between RPC, IPC, and named pipes?

Tags: windows, winapi, ipc, rpc, named-pipes

In essence, how exactly does RPC, IPC, and named pipes work together within a network? I am currently looking at how different Microsoft hosts can have processes communicate with each other using named pipes, but I do not understand what is happening over the network - some articles talk about "RPC over SMB" but how does that relate to named pipes? How does this communication relate to the use of filesystem shares?

Answer (score 2):

IPC is a general term, InterProcess Communication. It encompasses any method for one process to communicate with another, sometimes on the same machine, sometimes over a network.

Named pipes are simply a particular means of IPC. They are in many ways akin to TCP/IP, although generally only used on local networks rather than on the global internet.

RPC (Remote Procedure Call) is a protocol layered atop a particular IPC implementation. It enables a calling process to issue a function call that looks like any ordinary call in the given language and have that call handled by another process (again whether on the same machine or possibly over the network) RPC can be implemented on top of named pipes, TCP/IP and other lower-level network protocols. It is also possible to implement on a local machine using shared memory facilities provided by the operating system.

Comment: Thank you! So, does that mean RPC calls can be made to another local machine's share? So it would be something like a named pipe within a network share accessed by local clients who make calls via RPC. -- Or something like that

Comment: Yes, but there is an RPC protocol optimized for connections to processes on the same machine, for msrpc that is ncalrpc. It's possible to connect to a named pipe RPC endpoint on the same system, it's just not as efficient.